# How to make Alexa 'sing' jingle bells?

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I'm creating a seasonal Alexa skill, where there will be intents such as 'how many sleeps till Christmas', 'am I on the good list' etc; and I'd also like an intent to ask Alexa to **sing** Jingle Bells. The key part is making her **sing** it.

In my skill, for the `singJingleBells` intent, I output the the lyrics for Jingle Bells as the speech response, but Alexa *reads* the lyrics. (as expected if I'm honest).

I've discovered there is a (presumably official Amazon) skill to make her **sing** Jingle Bells. You can say `Alexa, sing Jingle Bells`

I would like my skill to do the same.

I'm guessing the Amazon skill does it with `SSML` phonetics, or more likely, a pre-recorded MP3 via either an `SSML audio` tag or `SSML speechcon interjection`

Is there anyway to discover/capture the output response of the Amazon skill so that I can understand (and copy!) the way it does it?

---

Using Steve's idea, I can use the console on echosim.io to capture the `SpeechSynthesizer`. Not sure if this gets me any closer?

```
{
    "directive": {
        "header": {
            "dialogRequestId": "dialogRequestId-6688b290-80d3-4111-a29d-4c60c6d47c31",
            "namespace": "SpeechSynthesizer",
            "name": "Speak",
            "messageId": "c5771361-2a80-4b00-beb6-22a783a7c504"
        },
        "payload": {
            "url": "cid:b438a3ea-d337-4c5f-b719-816e429ed473#Alexa3P:1.0/2017/11/06/20/94a9a7c4112b44568bff10df69d30825/01:18::TNIH_2V.f000372f-b147-4bea-81fb-4c2e7de67334ZXV/0_359577804",
            "token": "amzn1.as-ct.v1.Domain:Application:Knowledge#ACRI#b438a3ea-d337-4c5f-b719-816e429ed473#Alexa3P:1.0/2017/11/06/20/94a9a7c4112b44568bff10df69d30825/01:18::TNIH_2V.f000372f-b147-4bea-81fb-4c2e7de67334ZXV/0",
            "format": "AUDIO_MPEG"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey Nathan, your best bet is to ask around on [Amazon Skills Kit forum](https://forums.developer.amazon.com/spaces/23/Alexa+Skills+Kit.html). I highly doubt that you will be able to extract the response or SSML from a skill that you do not own. As this is proprietary information that the developer/owner of that skill owns. However, if you did find a way to achieve this, feel free to post an update here!

Comment: To add to my answer; you can currently see the audio played by Alexa using the [Test Simulator](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/devconsole/test-your-skill.html#test-simulator), see Device Logs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to get the Alexa audio output into an .mp3 file (or some other format) so that it can be played back again in a custom skill.

If that's the goal, you'll need to use the Alexa Voice Service (AVS) and more specifically the [SpeechSynthesizer Interface](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/alexa-voice-service/speechsynthesizer.html) to get the audio output that you'd then use in your custom skill response.

So, you'll be using both the Alexa Skills Kit (for the skill) and the Alexa Voice Service (AVS) to get the audio.

Comment: Thanks Steve, your answer put me on the right lines. What I did was to use echosim.io, and then use Chrome dev tools to capture the mpg request/response. Cheers

Comment: That's a clever hack Nathan! Glad to the answer was helpful and happy to know you have it figured out now.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an audio clip of 'Jingle Bells' using the [audio](/questions/tagged/audio) tag. A maximum of 5 audio tags can be used in a single output reponse.
 

The audio clip must following points.

- The MP3 must be hosted at an Internet-accessible HTTPS endpoint. HTTPS is required, and the domain hosting the MP3 file must present a valid, trusted SSL certificate. Self-signed certificates cannot be used.
- The MP3 must not contain any customer-specific or other sensitive information.
- The MP3 must be a valid MP3 file (MPEG version 2).
- The audio file cannot be longer than ninety (90) seconds.
- The bit rate must be 48 kbps. Note that this bit rate gives a good result when used with spoken content, but is generally not a high enough quality for music.
- The sample rate must be 16000 Hz. 
  Refer to this link for more clarity, [Audio Tag](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/speech-synthesis-markup-language-ssml-reference.html#audio)

Comment: Yes, I know about the `audio` tag, but what I really want is Amazon's version of Alexa singing it from their skill. The last sentence of my question says 'Is there anyway to discover/capture the output response of the Amazon skill so that I can understand (and copy!) the way it does it?'. If I could get the URL of the mp3 that they are using, I could write an `audio` tag using the same URL